# Ejecutar script de SQL desde Python

Tags: python, mysql, sql, python-3.x, sqlite

Tengo una duda, es si existe alguna manera de ejecutar sentencias que están guardadas en un script .sql desde un script de Python, en concreto las siguientes:

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS database;

CREATE TABLE "Traffic" (
    "Date"  VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    "Users" INTEGER(5) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY("Date")
);
```

Porque se que se pueden instanciar directamente como un string en Python pero me gustaría saber si hay alguna soución como digo de que las lea directamente de un .sql

Comment: Con  **[SQLAlchemy](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/index.html)** puedes probar, tiene soporte para distintos tipos de gestores de base de datos.

Answer (score 1):

Podrías con subprocess.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html

Pero te expone a vulnerabilidades porque tienes que proveer el usuario y la contraseña. Por ejemplo:

https://itecnote.com/tecnote/python-supplying-password-to-wrapped-up-mysql/

Los argumentos para /path/to/mysql están aquí:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql.html

Aunque algo genere el archivo de sql, sería mejor ejecutar las transacciones con puro python.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-example-connecting.html